# Excel 2003 bug at the 1st launch after creating file from c#

Tags: c#, office-interop, excel-2003

I am creating a new .xls file for the Microsoft Office 2003 from existing template in C# using .NET 4.0 and Excel Interop Object Library. My template already contains all needed data and various formulas so my task is just to change some cells which are used in formulas as parameters. I do this without any problem...

The problem appears when i try to open my new file: when the file is opened at 1st time addins of excel doesnt work and as the result all the formulas show me error messages like "#NAME". When i launch the file again - everything is ok...

This makes me angry....

Does anybody know where the problem could be? And what is the solution??

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Do you open it Excel 2010? If so, then Excel thinks it's with macros and displays it incorrectly.

Basically, #Name error appears when the formula inside the cell can't be interpreted or is unknown.

The problem is related to the path of formulas, I guess in the first launch it can't correctly find the formulas path so in the next launches it shows them correctly.

Comment: I am opening my file in 2003 office!(